# create a radial-gradient over a circle to deliver a 3D feel

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, imagick

[image: random circles]

I have been able to create a PHP-Imagick script which generates images like above. Now I would like to add gradient to these circles. Below is an example of an ideal result.

[image: circle with a gradient]

I am hoping to give these circles a 3-dimensional feel. Hopefully I would be able to control the x and y coordinates of this radial-gradient (so that it remains within the circle ), as well as the degree of feathering.

---

I am aware the method of creating a radial-gradient **on a canvas** with  `newPseudoImage()` method.

`$canvas->newPseudoImage(600,300,'radial-gradient:#999999-#333333');`

But thats not gonna help in this case because I am looking to create it inside a circle that is created via [ellipse() method](http://php.net/manual/en/imagickdraw.ellipse.php). Here is a stripped version of the code that helped me create the example-image. While I struggle to achieve this, I would greatly appreciate any idea, suggestions that may put me on right path or a solution.

```
$canvas = new Imagick();
$canvas->newImage(700,400,new ImagickPixel('#333333'));
$circle = new ImagickDraw();
$circle->setFillColor('#000000'); // transparent
$circle->ellipse( 350, 200, 150, 150, 0, 360);
$canvas->drawImage($circle);
$canvas->setImageFormat( "png" ); // set the image format to png
header("Content-Type: image/png"); // Output the image 
echo $canvas;
```

---

**UPDATE** : So what I have realized is, perhaps it is basically a matter of creating a child circle inside a circle ( and then additionally controlling the x-y coordinates so it remains within the mother circle). It was fairly easy to create a circle within a circle. Example image below.

[image: circle inside another circle]

---

Here is the updated code which helped achieve the image above.

```
$canvas = new Imagick();
$canvas->newImage(700,400,new ImagickPixel('#333333'));
$circle = new ImagickDraw();
    $circle->setFillColor('#000000'); // transparent
    $circle->ellipse( 350, 200, 150, 150, 0, 360);
    $circle->setFillColor('#FFFFFF'); // transparent
    $circle->ellipse( 300, 150, 50, 50, 0, 360);
$canvas->drawImage($circle);
$canvas->setImageFormat( "png" ); // set the image format to png
header("Content-Type: image/png"); // Output the image 
echo $canvas;
```

**At this stage** I am looking for a way to **feather the edges of the inner circle**. This relevant [article at imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/#blur_channel) looks like what I need, but it is a command line code. Can someone please help me convert the code into imagick/php syntax. OR perhaps suggest own solution. Thnx.

---

FINAL UPDATE : Taking a hint from @emcconville's answer I was finally able to create a circle with what I would say a good feathering. Example below.

[image: well feathered circle]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe MVG's gradient methods are handled by ImagickDraw class, at least from what I can tell. However, `ImagickDraw->push` & `ImagickDraw-pop` can be used to create DIY gradients and feathering.

```php
$background = new Imagick();
$background->newImage(700,400,new ImagickPixel('#333333'));


$orb = new ImagickDraw();

$orb->ellipse( 350, 200, 150, 150, 0, 360);
for($i=50; $i>0; $i--) {
    $orb->push();
    $color = 'gray' . (25 - (int)($i/2));
    $orb->setFillColor(new ImagickPixel($color));
    $orb->ellipse( 295, 120, $i, $i, 0, 360);
    $orb->pop();

}
$background->drawImage($orb);
```

[image: example 1]

Or...

```php
$color = 'gray' . (20 - (int)($i/3));
```

[image: example 2]

Or even...

```php
$color = $i > 29 ? 'gray'.(50-$i) : 'grey20';
```

[image: Example 3]

Color theory helps, as the example above only uses gray colorspace, but the general idea is to iterate over the light intensity of the highlight feature.

Using [ATop compose](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#atop) might be the easiest method, but would require manipulating the image instance after a figure was drawn.

```php
$background = new Imagick();
$background->newImage(700,400,new ImagickPixel('#333333'));
$orb = new ImagickDraw();
$orb->ellipse( 350, 200, 150, 150, 0, 360);
$background->drawImage($orb);
$highlight = new Imagick();
$highlight->newImage(700,400,new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
$orb = new ImagickDraw();
$orb->ellipse( 350, 200, 35, 35, 0, 360);
$highlight->drawImage($orb);
$highlight->negateImage(TRUE);
$highlight->blurImage(0,32);
$background->compositeImage($highlight, Imagick::COMPOSITE_ATOP, -50, -60);
```

[image: Example 4]

Comment: I would prefer your first method because the circle produced by the last . method looks somewhat squarish. I guess that could be corrected easily but I dont think this method will scale well if I have to deal with multiple circles.

Comment: Also I need to understand what this line is doing - `$color = 'gray' . (25 - (int)($i/2));`  I can understand the calculation that is happening but am confused about the role/context of `gray`. Where does it come from ? Is there a documentation on it where I could read more about it. Or any article somewhere about this method.

Comment: @gurung The role/context of `gray` leverages known colornames in Imagemagick (use `identify -list color` to view all values). I opted to use this method simply because the examples images are in grayscale. The variations of calculating the `grayXX` value simply demonstrate the freedom you have to control the rate/attack/decay of the gradient.

Comment: I found the reference around the bottom of this page on imagemagick site.- http://www.imagemagick.org/script/color.php. It appears that gray has a range eg. gray1-100, wherein you could cycle/loop through.

Comment: It would be great to have a scalable solution though. What would you suggest if the mother circle was some other color eg. red and the child circle was white ? Please elaborate in the answer block, comment area is really narrow for a good explanation.

Comment: Never Mind, I figured it out. Thanks for the help.